# Enlaces con Iframes

Tags: javascript, php, html

Buenas, necesito a través de iframes, mostrar información de un blog, construí 3 iframes que van mostrando las ultimas noticias, El problema es que tuve que hacerlo así, porque la pagina esta totalmente diferente al blog, ya que el blog es de Wordpress, y no tengo acceso al código, El problema es que quiero que la persona al pulsar en el enlace que esta dentro del IFRAME, aparezca en otra pestaña, ya que carga dentro del mismo iframe y rompe el diseño de la pagina

```html
<iframe style="margin-left:150px" src="https://inglesencasablogblog.wordpress.com/#post-380t" scrolling="no" width="800" height="300"></iframe>
    <iframe style="margin-left:150px" src="https://inglesencasablogblog.wordpress.com/#post-345" scrolling="no" width="800" height="300"></iframe>
    <iframe style="margin-left:150px" src="https://inglesencasablogblog.wordpress.com/#post-360" scrolling="no" width="800" height="300"></iframe>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eso es lo que pasa cuando doy click al enlace dentro del IFRAME

Comment: podrias incluir los tres frames y el error que te sale. gracias

Answer (score 1):

Si no tienes acceso al código de las páginas que estás usando en los iframes yo te recomendaría que intentases otra aproximación (aunque tiene más curro). Sería, si es posible, que accedieses al contenido de los blogs vía RSS (por ejemplo), así eres tu quien pinta el contenido como quiere y le das el comportamiento que quieras.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

Remplaza `target='blank'` por `onclick='window.open();'`

También puedes usar

```
<a target="_parent" href="http://url.org">link</a>
```

Si no tienes acceso, lo que se me imagina, es que puedes hacer:

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#iframe").load(function () {
                var ifr = document.getElementById("iframe")
                var anchors = ifr.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("a");
                for (var i in anchors) {
                    anchors[i].setAttribute("target", "_blank");
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: El problema es que el enlace esta dentro del IFRAME, o sea otra pagina y no tengo acceso a ella, por lo que no puedo modificar las URL, para poner el target, sino que todo tiene q ser dentro de la mia

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar, creo que el problema es que yo no puedo programar nada desde mi html, porque el IFRAME es otra pagina, la unica forma seria modificar el codigo de la otra pagina y ahi radica el problema que no tengo acceso a ese codigo

Comment: @CarlosEstarita he modificado mi respuesta

Comment: Nada, creo que la unica alternativa es que busque la manera de acceder al codigo de esa pagina, porque el sitio esta en Wordpress.com y no deja modificar el codigo, pero creo que programando lo que sea dejara modificar el IFRAME, porque eso es otra pagina dentro de esta y no creo q deje modificar la otra pagina desde la mia, al menos que use php, pero no tengo idea de como solventar ese problema

Comment: De hecho creo que estas en lo correcto, leyendo un poco mas de información creo que es por politicas de privacidad, te adjunto este link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe

Answer (score 0):

Si querés que cualquier enlace de tu iframe se abra en una pestaña, deberás de agregar en cada link el atributo target="_blank"

Ejemplo:

```
<a href="https://inglesencasablogblog.wordpress.com/acerca-de/" target="_blank" >SOBRE NOSOTROS
</a>
```